# Excel Pivot Chart show empty column when data is based on DAX formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dax, powerpivot

I appreciated that this question may be really daft, but I'm stumped.

I have a table from which a pivot table is created from. The base table is ostensibly a Testing schedule, I'm interested in 3 fields in my dashboard

[image]

In my dashboard I use a couple of measures to work out the number of cases that aren't passed 'cases remaining' and what that percent consists of 'remaining percent less passed'.

[image]

What I want is the 'Execution Priority' to always show all values - Critical, High, Medium and Low.

I'm really not sure how to do it, as 'Execution Priority' is just a standard column, it's not calculated. I've forced a '0' to appear in the rows when all cases are set to 'pass' using a '+0' on the end of the measure '=COUNTROWS(FILTER(Test_Schedule,Test_Schedule[Result] <> "Pass"))+0'

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your result by using CUBEVALUE and CUBEMEMBER functions.
Less convinient than regular PivotTable but PivotTable will drop and/or add values that are added to the model, therefore you can't really achieve "static" dashboard using PivotTable.

What I suggest for your isuue:
1. in dax create 2 measures:

```
countRows:=COUNTROWS(Table2)

countRowsNotPass:=IF(ISBLANK(COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table2,Table2[Result]<>"Pass"))),0,COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table2,Table2[Result]<>"Pass")))
```

2. In Excel create following calls for the measures

   =CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Measures].[countRows]")
   =CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Measures].[countRowsNotPass]")

   I have named these cells as CountR and CountN
3. Create a PivotTable from the model containing only "Functional area" at rows
4. Create a Cubemembers for each of the following: "Critical,High,Medium,Low,etc..." like so (just change the highlighted **Critical**  for each one in a group):

   =IFERROR(CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Table2].[Execution Priority].&[**Critical**]"),"**Critical**")

5.Create a function like this, this one should get you number of cases remaining:
   =IFERROR(CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel",CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Table2].[Functional Area].&["&$F4&"]"),Crit,CountN),0)

6. create another function this should give you a percentage of remaining cases:

=IFERROR(G4/CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel",CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Table2].[Functional Area].&["&$F4&"]"),Crit,CountR),0)

You should end up with something like that:
[image: Dashboard preview]

Let me know if that helped

Comment: To get off to a quick start creating static dashboards using CUBEVALUE etc. you can highlight a pivot table and go PivotTable Tools -> Analyse -> OLAP Tools -> Convert to formulas. This will change a pivot table to be a static dashboard with all the appropriate formulas.

Comment: @TDP you are right, I prefer the straight forward approach. beside one issue, in that particular case ( if you transform you PivotTable to formulas) if it will be added new areas, nothing will happen hence it will be "Hardcoded" functions...

Comment: Thanks for the help! In points 5 and 6 I initially had to name 'crit' and "Critical". I assume this is because you defined a name of the value as 'crit'?

Comment: @PaulColes exactly, it was just more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to change a pivot table so that it does not suppress empty column and rows in a returned data set.

Right click on the pivot table --> Pivot Table Options then go to the Display tab.

On that there is options for show items with no data on rows and one for column.

If you pick columns, it will always show all of your execution priority values, even when the returned value for that column is null/empty.

Comment: I had previously tried this, but to no avail, I believe it doesn't work because I'm not pulling data from the truth table, I'm generating it from measures.

I only really wanted to do it so that the formatting didn't keep changing, I've set this with conditional formatting now.

Would love to know if my stupid Idea is possible though!